# DOM updated twice inside of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've been struggling with this for a couple of days; I've got this recursive directive:

```
app.directive('block', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            block: '=',
            childName: '=',
            addChild: '=',
            clicked:'=',
            allBlocks: '='
        },
        template: '<div>' +
            '<p class="blocke"> {{block.title}} </p>' +
            '<input class="childButton" ng-model="childName[block.title]" type="text"        placeholder="child name">' +
            '<button class="childButton" ng-click="addChild(block.title)" >Add child to {{block.title}} </button>' +
            '</div>',
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.$watch("block.childBlocks",function () {
                if (angular.isArray($scope.block.childBlocks) && $scope.block.childBlocks.length > 0) {
                    if(document.getElementsByClassName("blocke").length < Object.keys($scope.allBlocks).length) {
                        $element.append('<block ng-repeat="childBlock in block.childBlocks" block="childBlock" child-name="childName" add-child="addChild" all-blocks="allBlocks"></block>');
                        $compile($element.contents()[$element.contents().length-1])($scope);
                    }
                }
            }, true); 
        }
    };
}]);
```

This directive is supposed to add an instance of itself everytime a modification occurs in an "n" array. Such modifications are made by this function:

```
$scope.addChild = function(indexe){
    var temp = {'title':$scope.childName[indexe],'childBlocks':[]};
    $scope.allBlocks[indexe].childBlocks.push(temp);
    $scope.allBlocks[$scope.childName[indexe]]=temp;
}
```

My problem is that if I keep the second if test, `if(document.getElementsByClassName("blocke").length < Object.keys($scope.allBlocks).length)`, the scope seems to stay the same whatever I do and so I always append the same block to the first block.

But if I remove this test, the watch function is triggered twice and I end up appending both the block and it's child twice. For me it's a weird kind of behavior, but I'm new to directives.

I guess it must come from the `addChild()` function which modifies `$scope.allBlocks` twice, but I can't figure why.

EDIT : 
I've been trying complicated stuff for 2 days but the only workaround that works is this :

```
link: function($scope, $element) {
var i =0;
$scope.$watch("block.childBlocks",function () {
            if (angular.isArray($scope.block.childBlocks) && $scope.block.childBlocks.length > 0){
                if(i==0) {
                    $element.append('<block ng-repeat="childBlock in block.childBlocks" block="childBlock" child-name="childName" add-child="addChild" all-blocks="allBlocks"></block>');
                    $compile($element.contents()[$element.contents().length-1])($scope);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        },true); 
}
```

Yes just a var ....